# wget distinguish header from body in output

Tags: wget

In the output of

```
wget www.google.com --save-headers --output-document - --quiet
```

how can you tell which lines are the headers and where the body starts (*e.g.,* to `tee` the different parts into different pipelines)

**Update**

```
# r=$(wget www.google.com --save-headers --output-document - --quiet)
# status=$(echo $r | grep HTTP | awk '{ print $2 }')
# body=$(echo $r | awk '{ if( body ){ print $0 };if( $0 ~ /^$/ ){ body=1 } }')
```

However, `$body` is empty.

**Uodate 2**

```
body=$(echo "$r" | awk '{ if( $1 ~ /^[\s\r\n]*$/ ) { b=1 }; if( b ) { print $0 } }')
```

Quotes around `$r`. What a bugger.

Answer (score 1):

> how can you tell which lines are the headers and where the body starts

[`RFC1945`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) stipulates that

> The entity body is separated from the headers by a null line (i.e., a
> line with nothing preceding the CRLF).

so headers are before first blank line and body after said line in HTTP response. [`--save-headers` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html) of GNU wget does follow suit

> Save the headers sent by the HTTP server to the file, preceding the
> actual contents, with an empty line as the separator.

As `CRLF` line endings are used headers are before first `CRLFCRLF` (`\r\n\r\n`) and body is after it. I would use `python` for that part following way, first download response as file named `response`

```
wget www.example.com --save-headers --output-document response --quiet
```

then create `splitter.py` as follows

```
with open("response", "rb") as f:
    headers, body = f.read().split(b"\r\n\r\n", 1)
with open("headers", "wb") as f:
    f.write(headers)
    f.write(b"\r\n")
with open("body", "wb") as f:
    f.write(body)
```

and run it

```
python splitter.py
```

I use binary (`b`) mode so it would work with any encoding and write `\r\n` after headers as it is CRLF of last key-value pair. Feel free to use any other tool you are comfortable working for making split.

Comment: AHA! It's the first blank line. (Hate python.)

Answer (score 0):

```
r=$(wget www.example.com --save-headers --quiet --load-cookies /root/cookies.txt --save-cookies /root/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --output-document - 2>/dev/null )

status=$(echo "$r" | grep HTTP | awk '{ print $2 }')

if [ "$status" = "200" ]; then
        body=$(echo "$r" | awk '{ if( body ){ print $0 };if( $0 ~ /^[\s\r\n]*$/ ){ body=1 } }')
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `\s` suggest you are using GNU `AWK` if this is case you might extract body by doing `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n\r\n"}NR>1'`